# Most efficient way for users to accept terms when registering?

Tags: terms-of-service

I have a register form on my website which currently has text just above the submit button as such `By signing up you agree to our Terms of Service` (Notice - `Terms of Service` is underlined and links to the terms)

I feel that this may possibly be deceiving however it is more convenient for users then having a checkbox.

So the ultimate question is, text or checkbox?

Comment: This is actually a legal question (opt in vs. opt out). Your client/company may already have a stance on this.

Comment: This is my own website, so I have no stance on this yet.

Comment: If you have a TOS on your site, you *should* have a stance on it. Do you have a lawyer helping with the TOS? What *is* the TOS? Context is going to be really important here.

Comment: I'm creating this website alone (and I'm a teenager) so I have no lawyer to help. I used automattic's terms of conditions and edited it to fit my website as they allow others to use it for their own needs for free.

Comment: Well, a TOS *is* a legal contract. So you likely shouldn't be using one unless you are fully aware of the legal ramifications of what is in it. To answer your specific question, I'd say: If the TOS are relatively benign, use just text. If the TOS is complex and has real ramifications for the end users, make sure you encourage them to read them in any way you can and a checkbox (opt-in) would help with that.

Comment: Also read this, [Automatic agreement to terms of service](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33119/automatic-agreement-to-terms-of-service?rq=1), I would presume that having no checkbox is about the same as having it already checked. So like the answer says you may not be given any legal protection doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, from a UX perspective, it is easier to click a button than to check a box AND click a button.

Whether it is easier/more engaging to just display the text, or to require the user to check a box, is a secondary question here. The more important question is whether there is anything important in the TOS that they need to know before agreeing.

Try to anticipate what parts of the TOS are most relevant to your users, and call attention to them. Think of how most mobile app updates will recap what permissions the app has. This is separate from the TOS, but is displayed prominently and regularly because it is likely to be important.

Are there certain restrictions or conditions on the use of your site? Perhaps pull those out as bullet points.

Also, it's worth keeping in mind that TOS are in [a legal grey area](http://thenextweb.com/law/2012/04/11/good-news-breaking-that-tos-wont-land-you-in-jail/). There is a judicial precedent that, because it is unreasonable for an individual to read ALL of the TOS they might encounter (because some of them are ridiculously long), the federal stance is not to prosecute minor violations. So just because you get people to read/agree to a TOS doesn't mean you'll have any control over what they do. This brings us back to DA01's question: why do you really need a TOS?

Comment: Great answer. I'm have terms of service as I'm collecting users information, such as full name, email, location etc, I'm using advertisements with Google AdSense and lastly because there is a level of user to user interaction so I must state I am not responsible for their content.

Comment: That makes sense then. As long as you can make it clear to the user that that is what the TOS represents, do whatever is easiest AND fulfills any legal requirements. Some quick googling suggests that there are no universal legal requirements for this, but that a dedicated button to accept is a good idea.

Comment: I guess I should a checkbox for accepting the TOS then, thanks.

Comment: @PhillipQuintero You wrote: "Speaking strictly from a UX perspective." What if the UX perspective is a measure of how clearly the user has understood, rather than how easily the user clicked through? I wonder if the ethical thing wouldn't be to require a separate click: "I agree to the terms of service, including about my responsibility for the content I post, how the site uses my data, and more." I bet this wouldn't convert as well, but sooner or later there'll be a court case that decides getting a user to click a generic check box doesn't constitute obtaining informed consent. :o

Comment: @JeromeR, agree completely. Pav needs to make sure the user understands as clearly as possible what they are agreeing to before devoting time towards making it easier to do so.

I would argue that a check-box is not going to help with this unless it is coupled with some kind of summary or paraphrasing of the typically long and complicated language used in a TOS.

Comment: @PavSidhu - Check out the Terms of Service; Didn't Read project if you haven't already. They assign ratings to various popular services based on how user-friendly their TOS is, and break down common TOS elements by topic. tosdr.org